# A question related to total positivity of $A+A^{\circ -1}$

Tags: matrices, reference-request

Is there any result known related to total positivity (or any other proprety) of the matrix $\left[a_{ij}+\frac{1}{a_{ij}}\right]$, if $A = [a_{ij}]$ be any matrix with non zero entries?

Any help please.